# List boots with unix timestamps via journalctl

Tags: systemd, boot, journalctl

`journalctl` has the `-o short-unix` flag that I can use to change the output date format on stuff like -t systemd-sleep.

But the only way I've found to list boots is `--list-boots`, and this doesn't seem to obey the `-o` flag.

Is there a way to make journalctl list boots with unix timestamps? Since systemd is here to stay I fear other methods might break in the future, but I'm open to those suggestions too.

Comment: You can however convert those fields into unix timestamps. I.e: `journalctl --list-boots | awk '{ d2ts="date -d \""$3" "$4" " $5"\" +%s"; d2ts | getline $(NF+1); close(d2ts)} 1'`

Comment: Thanks. Still a bit confused on how this works, but it should do the job as long as the format doesn't change much.

Comment: @ madprops, posted the above as an answer so it is better searchable and probably more useful to others than having it just as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can however convert those fields into unix timestamps. 
I.e:

```
journalctl --list-boots | awk '{ d2ts="date -d \""$3" "$4" " $5"\" +%s"; d2ts | getline $(NF+1); close(d2ts)} 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternative tool called `tuptime` to get exact the same information. As example:

```
tuptime -bits
```